# Advice with optimising the post_meta in my phpmyadmin file

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to optimize my site's database using PHPMyAdmin.
I want to know if it is safe to delete "post_meta" as it has occupied more than 1 GB of my database?

update: I removed all the post revisions, spam comments etc, along with all the plugin data using `https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugins-garbage-collector/`. However, i still see my postmeta DB contains 1GB. When i look inside, i can still see a lot of old plugin files. I followed this command: https://crunchify.com/better-optimize-wordpress-database.../. to remove some of the files. However, i am confused if this is the right and the shortest way to fix this issue. Or there is any other way to clean the old plugin data from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that MySQL usually expands the size of its files on disk as needed, but doesn't shrink them. Deleting old data won't reclaim that disk space automatically. You can supposedly use the SQL command `OPTIMIZE TABLE <table_name>;` to do that manually, but you'll have to do it per table. I say "supposedly" because I've seen differing reports on whether this works to reclaim *all* the disk space from deleted rows, or if it only reclaims disk space from outdated indexes.

Next, I would not delete an entire table. It's almost certain that WordPress will stop functioning properly if it can't access the `post_meta` table. Even removing individual entries risks corrupting your data in strange ways, where one post may link to another but if it's missing, WordPress will show an error because of the missing post, things like that.

Finally, to specifically address your last question "[I]s [there] any other way to clean the old plugin data from phpmyadmin?" I highly suggest using WordPress-aware tools for this job. You *can* delete data from your database directly using phpMyAdmin (by either structuring a query properly or just going through and using the delete icon to remove a row you don't want), but not in a way that will be aware of how WordPress processes the data and relationships between tables. There are probably tools meant specifically for that job that would make things easier for you.